# Getting error "415 Unsupported Media Type" while posting data in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project of AngularJS. I post data in 'form data' type using $http.post in angularjs.
but it shows an error: "415 Unsupported Media Type"

```
angular.module('odeskApp') 
 .factory('Password', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        update: function (pwd) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http.post('/api/user/password', { 'password': pwd }, {
    headers: {
     'Accept': '*/*',
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
     },
    transformRequest: function(data) { // If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
                    if ( ! angular.isObject( data ) ) {

                        return( ( data == null ) ? "" : data.toString() );

                    }

                    var buffer = [];

                    // Serialize each key in the object.
                    for ( var name in data ) {

                        if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {

                            continue;

                        }

                        var value = data[ name ];

                        buffer.push(
                            encodeURIComponent( name ) +
                            "=" +
                            encodeURIComponent( ( value == null ) ? "" : value )
                        );

                    }

                    // Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
                    var source = buffer
                        .join( "&" )
                        .replace( /%20/g, "+" )
                    ;

                    return( source ); }
  })
                .success(function (data) {alert("success");
                    $('#changePasswordAlert .alert-success').show();
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert-danger').hide();
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
                    deferred.resolve(data); //resolve data
               })
                .error(function (err) { 
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert-danger').show();
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert-success').hide();
     deferred.reject();
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
    });
            return deferred.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

I don't know what happens here. I define the headers also. Please suggest any possible solution or please do let me know if any extra information required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably because you are specifying `Content-Type` as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` but the data you are sending is a JSON object. Hence the server is receiving content that is different from what it's expecting. Change it to read:

```
Content-Type: 'application/json'
```

That should fix the error.